# Django - How to put responses in an array (DICT in LIST)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is the response that I want to have:

```
[
    {
        "id": "e27509e4-0abf-4747-be65-862d6d4092b0",
        "name": "Price 20200826",
        "description": "Price 20200826",
        "is_default": "True"
    },
    {
        "id": "36484103-cf76-47eb-8bfb-d5c281a5ec04",
        "name": "price_20200922",
        "description": "Price 20200922",
        "is_default": "False"
    }
]
```

I did this:

```
query = B2CPriceGroup.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default')
return HttpResponse(query)
```

Got this (not in an array)

```
{'id': UUID('e27509e4-0abf-4747-be65-862d6d4092b0'), 'name': 'Price 20200826', 'description': 'Price 20200826', 'is_default': True}
{'id': UUID('36484103-cf76-47eb-8bfb-d5c281a5ec04'), 'name': 'price_20200922', 'description': 'Price 20200922', 'is_default': False}
```

---

```
query = B2CPriceGroup.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default')
        return JsonResponse(query, safe = False)
```

Got this

```
TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

---

When I did this

```
query = [B2CPriceGroup.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default')]
return HttpResponse(query)
```

I got this (seem not to be JSON type)

```
<QuerySet [{'id': UUID('e27509e4-0abf-4747-be65-862d6d4092b0'), 'name': 'Price 20200826',
```

Please help, It is necessary to output the exact the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using django-rest-framework then straigtway use `ModelSerializer`

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from yourWebapp.models import B2CPriceGroup

class B2CPriceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B2CPriceGroup
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default']
```

**API views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import B2CPriceGroupSerializer
from yourWebapp.models import B2CPriceGroup

@api_view(['GET']) #Or mention your request method like 'POST'
def B2CPriceGroup_api_view(request):
    qs = B2CPriceGroup.objects.all()
    serializer = B2CPriceGroupSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Or if you want to go by your approach then in your normal views.py you can do this to.

```
query = B2CPriceGroup.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default')
queryList = list(query)
return JsonResponse({"data":queryList})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should convert Queryset to a list to avoid TypeError.

```
query = list(B2CPriceGroup.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_default'))
return JsonResponse(query, safe = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error: `TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`

Inside your model class just add `__json__` method like this:

```
    def __json__(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'is_default': self.is_default,
        }
```